# Do you need to schedule a new biometrics appointment each time you apply for a UK Visa?

Tags: biometric-passports

My son was refused a UK Visa for not supplying adequate information.  We have since compiled all of that information. NOW -  Do you need to schedule a new biometrics appointment each time you apply for a UK Visa?

Comment: Yes, biometrics must be collected each and every time.

Comment: Was the application actually refused, or did you receive a notice that you have to supply more info before it can be processed?

Comment: @brhans the application will be refused under Part 9 of the Immigration Rules. If the person refuses during a removal from port, it's a 10 year ban.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One reference for this requirement is in this [letter from the UKBA](http://www.emcouncils.gov.uk/write/UKBA%20Charging%20for%20Immigration%20and%20Nationality%20Services.pdf).

> Applicants for a long term visit visa benefit from the convenience of
>   not having to make multiple visa applications, each **requiring their
>   biometrics to be taken**, **each time** they want to come to the UK

The logical reason for this is to prevent someone else applying using your identity.